# Is it safe to use exceptions in an injected class across dll/so?

Tags: c++, exception, shared-libraries

I have a dll or shared object, MyDll which produces an object, ForeignObject:

```
class ForeignObject : public LocalInterface {
  virtual void some_func(Injector& i) {
    i.inject();
  }
};
```

In the interfaces looks like this.

```
class Injector {
  virtual void inject() = 0;
};

class LocalInterface {
  virtual void some_func(Injector& i) = 0;
};
```

Then I do the following:

```
class MyInjector : public Injector {
  virtual void inject() {throw std::runtime_error("arrgghh");}
};

int main() {
  LocalInterface* foreign_obj = create_object_from_my_dll();
  MyInjector injector;
  foreign_obj->some_func(injector);
  destroy_object_from_my_dll(foreign_obj);
  return 0;
}
```

My question is, **why** is it **safe/not safe** to throw an exception like this. Is it safe when they are built with the same compiler? Between compilers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the answer will depend on the OS. But for all the UNICES I've worked with (including Linux and Mac OS X), it will be safe. Of course, you need to compile with compilers using the same ABI, but the ABI of g++ hasn't changed in years (can't remember exactly, but I think 3.2 was the last big change). Also, in the model used in Linux, linkage don't impact code behaviour. So you can safely put any code in a dynamically linked file (i.e. shared object file), it will work as if it is linked statically.

On Windows, if you use VC++, then you won't be able to compile your library with another compiler. The program and the library must use the same version of VC++, there is no compatibility in either direction. If you are using g++, you can compile with another version of g++ (like on UNIX), but not with VC++. As for the question of it this is dangerous, I will let a windows-specialist answer as DLL have weird behaviour, and if I remember an object should always be destroyed within the scope of the DLL that loaded it, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: You say it depend on OS, but does every compiler on Linux follow the same ABI (excluding g++ <3.2)?

Comment: It seems gcc and clang both use the Itanium C++ ABI (cf. http://sourcery.mentor.com/public/cxx-abi/abi.html ), which is a standard ABI. So you should be able to check if your C++ compiler use this ABI or if it can be configured to use it. However, it is not the only ABI that exists, so you cannot be sure all C++ compiler will use the same ABI, on Linux or not.

Comment: @daramarak note that clang for example uses the same Itanium ABI as gcc. So code can be compiled with either without problem.

Comment: +1 Clang and g++ covers a great deal which is of interest for me at least. For other compilers I will just have to look up the ABI.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe if and only if you build it with the same compiler ( same runtime lib ) but in case of different runtime lib it will generate a memory corruption in your program and crash. In general there is not any special problem with exception but with a class exporting from dll. You exception will be exported and this is a problem.

Comment: The class that creates the exception is not exported it is injected into the the dll/so.

Comment: Are you saying that functions created within the main of the program is run in with runtime library of the dll? As I understand it the construction of the runtime error is already compiled in the main program. That would also be the case for copy construction and such.

Comment: The runtime_error class should be in the runtime library so in case you have a different implementation of runtime library it will cause a memory corruption because the different sizes in compiled structs.

In general I mean that you have other runtime_error class structure than this one in dll file. No function created within main program running with the runtime which you use to compile it, functions in dll running with runtime developer used to create this dll.

Comment: Functions (usually) work just fine between dlls, passing pointers and refs too. The actual throwing of the exception is a simple callback. Memory corruption can occur if I new in one runtime and delete in another but this example does nothing else than passing pointers and call function. The actual resolution of the exception might be a whole other story.

Comment: throw std::runtime_error("arrgghh"); this line will generate a new instance of std::runtime_error class. Which will be passed to your main program so after that you will get an object from another runtime in your main application this is what do I mean.

Comment: I am sorry but you are wrong. The generation of the error is code compiled in the main program, which calls into the runtime of the main program. So the exception is created in the main program, it just passes through the dll.